# Bandwidth throttling per user group

Tags: networking, iptables, bandwidth, tc

I am wondering if it is possible to create a bandwidth shaping/throttling script that shapes traffic based on user group. That is, if user1, user2, are in user group group1, they will have 1mb/s download and 1mb/s upload, whilst if user3 and user4 are in group2, they will have 256kb/s download and 256kb/s upload.

I've read a bit about this and I found some iptables and TC implementations of a per user solution, but I have not seen anything for a user group.

Hopefully it can be simply implemented in form of a custom iptables rules and script running with TC or the like. Here is a script I was looking into that does a system wide throttle: http://atmail.com/kb/2009/throttling-bandwidth/

I assume it is possible to do user group throttling since it is possible for throttling on a per user basis.

Thanks for any info you can provide for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Look — [man iptables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) mentions module `owner` which allows to select packets related to users/groups but only outgoing ones (`OUTPUT` and `POSTROUTING`) but since Linux' netfilter also has rather  excellent connection tracking support you can bring into the game module `connmark` and have separated corresponding ingress traffic as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. This is going to be for limiting traffic for ssh tunnels, so I assume if I limit the user groups outgoing bandwidth their tunnels bandwidth will also throttle. Thanks for this I will research more into the owner module.

Comment: @RobReylen, yep, feel free to hire in case you need this tried ASAP